# How to import CSV into database on Rails whilst skipping callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, csv

I am currently trying to import over 40 CSV's exported from sqlite3 into oracle db but I seem to have issues whilst importing ***some*** of the CSV's, into the corresponding tables.

The code line with:

> `class_name.create!(row.to_hash)`

produces errors on some classes because the callbacks are also triggered when the

> `.create!()` method is called

```
def import_csv_into_db
  Dir.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export')) do |filename|
      next if filename == '.' or filename == '..' or filename == 'extract_db_into_csv.sh' or filename =='import_csv.rb'
      filename_renamed = File.basename(filename, File.extname(filename)).chomp('s').titleize.gsub(/\s+/, "")
        CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export',filename), headers: true) do |row|
          class_name = Object.const_get(filename_renamed)
          puts class_name
          class_name.create!(row.to_hash)
          puts "Insert on table #{class_name}s complete with:  #{row.to_hash}"
      end
  end
end
```

The issue at hand is that my CSV import function is in the `seeds.rb`, so whenver I run `bundle exec rake db:seed` the CSV's are imported.

How exactly can I avoid the callbacks being triggered when `class_name.create!(row.to_hash)` is triggered within the function in the `seeds.rb` ?

In my `customer.rb` I have callbacks such as:

> `after_create :add_default_user` or `after_create :add_build_config`

I'd like to manipulate my function within the `seeds.rb` to skip the callbacks when the function tries importing a CSV file like `customers.csv` (which would logically call `Customer.create!(row.to_hash)`).

Comment: You can replace `.chomp('s').titleize.gsub(/\s+/, "")` with [`.gsub(/\s+/, "").classify`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) and `Object.const_get(filename_renamed)` with [`constantize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize). `Dir.foreach` can be replaced with [`Dir.children`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.4/Dir.html#method-c-children) which skips `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are lower level methods which will not run callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks). For example, instead of `create!` you can call [`insert!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert-21). Instead of `destroy` you can call [`delete`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-delete).

Side note: use [`insert_all!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all-21) to bulk insert multiple rows at once. Your import will be much faster and it does not use validations. Though I would recommend the more flexible [`active-import`](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) instead.

---

However, skipping callbacks might cause problems if they are necessary for the integrity of the data. If you `delete` instead of `destroy` associated data may not be deleted, or you may get errors because of referential integrity. Be sure to add [`on delete` actions on your foreign keys](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) to avoid this. Then the database itself will take care of it.

Consider whether your db:seeds is doing too much. If importing this CSV is a hindrance to seeding the database, consider if it should be a separate [rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737696/what-is-rake-and-how-it-is-used-in-rails) instead.

Consider whether your callbacks can be rewritten to be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning), that is to be able to run multiple times. For example, `after_create :add_default_user` should recognize there already is a default user and not try to re-add it.

Finally, consider whether callbacks which are run every time a model is created are the correct place to do this work.

Comment: thank you! What difference does the exclamation mark in front of create! or insert! make?  Thanks for all the tips, ill be sure to do some digging and adjustment  :) @schwern

Comment: @Naj If the create or insert fails it will throw an exception rather than returning `nil`. You generally want to use the `!` version of all database methods and handle the exceptions. If you don't, your code will silently fail.

Comment: Thanks. So i tried running it with insert! and got `NoMethodError: undefined method insert!' for #<Class:0x32d8710a>` What could the reason be for this? Why would create! work and insert! return a no method error? @schwern

Comment: @Naj [`insert!` was added in Rails 6](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert%21).

Comment: what do i do if i dont have rails 6, my siuation currently wont allow me to upgrade without ruining everything else, how do I skip callbacks in rails 5.2?

Comment: @Naj Use activerecord-import. Or redesign your callbacks and/or db:seed. Probably the second.